# Calculate the sum of time based on classification in different column

Tags: python, pandas

I want to calculate the time accumulated in the TIZ column based on appearance of its values (Zone1, Zone2, Zone3).For example line 0-4 are Zone 3 = 50s

```
    Time    Variable    TIZ
0   00:00:00    0.4001  Zone3
1   00:00:05    0.3910  Zone3
2   00:00:10    0.3839  Zone3
3   00:00:15    0.3696  Zone3
4   00:00:20    0.3858  Zone3
... ... ... ...
805 01:07:05    1.3741  Zone1
806 01:07:10    1.3786  Zone1
807 01:07:15    1.3260  Zone1
808 01:07:20    1.2819  Zone1
809 01:07:25    1.4229  Zone1
```

I tried this for the Variable column:

```
data.loc[data["TIZ"] == "Zone1", "Variable"].sum()
```

which works well, but I don't know how to handle the datetime format for this condition.

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: The overall duration was 67min. Of these 67min 30min was in Zone1 20 min in Zone 2 and the remaining in Zone3 (just an example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

does this answer your question?

```
# convert time to seconds and then convert back the sum value to time format
(df.assign(ts=pd.to_timedelta(df['Time']).dt.total_seconds())
 .groupby('TIZ')['ts'].sum()
 .apply(pd.to_timedelta, unit='s')
)
```

```
TIZ
Zone1   0 days 05:36:15
Zone3   0 days 00:00:50
Name: ts, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

to get the max time for each zone

```
df.groupby('TIZ')['Time'].max()
```

```
TIZ
Zone1    01:07:25
Zone3    00:00:20
Name: Time, dtype: object
```

data used

```
data = {'Time': {0: '00:00:00',  1: '00:00:05',  2: '00:00:10',  3: '00:00:15',  4: '00:00:20',  805: '01:07:05',  806: '01:07:10',  807: '01:07:15',  808: '01:07:20',  809: '01:07:25'}, 
'Variable': {0: 0.4001,  1: 0.391,  2: 0.3839,  3: 0.3696,  4: 0.3858,  805: 1.3741,  806: 1.3786,  807: 1.326,  808: 1.2819,  809: 1.4229},
 'TIZ': {0: 'Zone3',  1: 'Zone3',  2: 'Zone3',  3: 'Zone3',  4: 'Zone3',  805: 'Zone1',  806: 'Zone1',  807: 'Zone1',  808: 'Zone1',  809: 'Zone1'}}

df=pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

Comment: I think my idea seems more complex (really sorry for my bad explanation...) I'm new to coding. I assume that I will get the total time for each zone by adding the corresponding time value, iE 00:00:05 + 00:00:10 = 00:00:15 if TIZ = zone3 (example)

Comment: My output shows this for TIZ, which does not correspond to the total time
Zone1    0 days 16:35:05
Zone2   10 days 16:13:10
Zone3    7 days 14:15:30
Name: ts, dtype: timedelta64[ns]

Comment: your solution worked now, I just took the sample rate of 5s for each row in the column time, after applying your function I got the results I wanted, thanks.